# Laravel form uses ajax just when checkbox is manually checked

Tags: ajax, laravel, post

I cannot understand this:

I have a Laravel form. In the controller, I set up the consideration that the form might store data via ajax, and I have also put a fallback non-ajax for another part of the site, where ajax is not used:

```
public function store(Requests\EntryRequest $request) {

    $journal = new Article($request->all());
        if ( Request::ajax() ) {
            Auth::user()->articles()->save($journal);
            return response(['msg' => 'Daily entry saved', 'status' => 'success']);
        } else {
            Auth::user()->articles()->save($journal);
            return redirect('home')->with('message', 'Daily entry saved');
        }
   }
```

So far so good. My form contains a checkbox, and also a hidden input in order to help sending a value with the form if the user doesn´t touch the checkbox (I remove the hidden value later on if the real checkbox is checked)

```
{!! Form::hidden('doctor', '0', ['type'=>'hidden', 'id'=>'drhelp'] ) !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('doctor', '1', false , ['class' => 'checkbox', 'data-toggle'=>'toggle', 'data-onstyle'=>'success', 'id'=>'drcheck']) !!}
```

And the form is being sent like this, nothing special:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/articles/',
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function( msg ) {
          //do things after success
      }
});
```

My question: Why does the form works through Ajax JUST when I manually change the checkbox. For instance, it opens unchecked, so if I want to post it unchecked, I must check it and uncheck it again. If I don´t touch it, the form just goes via regular submit.

And yet, if I interact with the checkbox, the form goes through Ajax POST. What is the problem here?

Thanks so much

Comment: Show the rest of the JavaScript.

Comment: I just realized what was the problem: the closing bracket of an on change event for the checkbox was wrongly placed AFTER the ajax calls... therefore, the ajax only worked when the checkbox was changed. I have no idea why it happens that no matter how many days you spend in a problem, you only realize about the solution a few minutes after posting the first request for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my better way to handle that is to add default value to check box from migration

```
$table->boolean('doctor')->default(false);
```

then you dont have to add hidden input and this will be enough

```
{!! Form::checkbox('doctor', true, false , ['class' => 'checkbox', 'data-toggle'=>'toggle', 'data-onstyle'=>'success', 'id'=>'drcheck']) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice approach. This is my first project with Laravel, so I didn´t know that. I already found the problem, but I will accept your answer as it´s a useful trick.